# Embedded: 4-wire resistive touchscreen

Tags: c, touchscreen, microchip

I am trying to interface a 4-wire resistive touchscreen to a PIC24FJ256 from Microchip. This is my first time using these and am looking for guidance as to how to go about it.

All I could find is a driver from Microchip called "ResTouchScreen.c". Before I go ahead and study this driver, has anyone written a library for handling resistive touch screens ? How complex is this task ?

Thanks !
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with these micros on a regular basis, and did once a project involving a 4 wire resistive touchscreen, although it was connect to an embedded computer instead of a PIC. What I did was to hook a touchscreen driver between the embedded computer and the touchscreen.

However, I think that what you actually want to do is to read the touchscreen directly with the micro. In this regard there is much info in the web, but I find that you can do as suggested in [this appnote](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://www.eetindia.co.in/STATIC/PDF/200811/EEIOL_2008NOV17_OPTO_AN_01.pdf&rct=j&q=4%20wire%20touch%20screen&ei=f5UcTsPIDMfusgaIhc2ABw&usg=AFQjCNHmp-gZA5iYWM21v8kpBw2nDgQ8QQ&sig2=8KtiUJDbjYtEUXtxQeTPqw). It talks about using an msp430, but the micro you are using can be also used in the same way since it has all the peripherals needed.

I hope it is a bit more clear now.